# Creating a quick look style zooming effect

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics

I would like to create an effect than an image zooms up from a thumbnail size to full screen.

I am not sure what's the right steps to achieve this. Should I create a transparent full screen window and animate a layer on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this CoreGraphics example](http://lipidity.com/apple/the-ultimate-core-graphics-resource). Specifically, take a look at the "grow" and "shrink" animations. That's how Apple does it, and that's what you'll want to do too.

Comment: That stuff relies on unsupported, private Apple code, so watch out if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of a transparent window with a CALayer inside is probably the best supported way to do it.

One thing that seems like it should be a good solution (at least it's the first thing I thought of when I wanted to do this) but **isn't** is NSView's `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:`. If memory serves, it was originally meant to do what you're talking about here, but the animation was taken out and it generally doesn't work that well now.